# Form_for generates resource path ending with '.1'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-for

I have a resource called :school and when I call form_for(@school) it generates the form action:

/school.1

I'm new to all this so any clues as to why it's doing that would be much appreciated. Sleep deprived and heading for a deadline in 3 hours, arrrggg!

Thanks :)

routes.rb:

```
resource:school
```

school.rb:

```
<%= form_for(@school, :url => school_path) do |f| %>
  <% if @school.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@school.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this school from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @school.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address1 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address2 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address2 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address3 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address3 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :town %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :town %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :county %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :county %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :postcode %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :postcode %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :local_authority_id %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :local_authority_id, LocalAuthority.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <% if current_user.person.primary_user? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label 'Are you happy for us to send you regular updates about VRH?' %><br />
      <%= f.check_box :allow_contact %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's in `@school`, and more importantly, what's in your `routes.rb`...

Comment: @school is an ActiveRecord object. I've got a route defined as: resource :school

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using the singular resource method you are telling rails that only one of these objects exist, in your routes file I think you need to change your resource :school to...

```
resources :schools
```

If however you do want only one school then I think you will need to add the url option to form_for...

```
<% form_for(@school, :url => school_path) %>
```

**Proposed solution for follow up questions...**

I think what you need will be something like this...

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :schools
end
resources :schools

# app/controllers/schools_controller.rb
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @school = @user.build_school
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @school = @user.build_school(params[:school])
    if @school.save
      # success...
    else
      # fail...
    end
  end

  def edit
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    if @school.update_attributes(params[:school])
      # success
    else
      # fail
    end
  end
end

# app/views/schools/new.html.erb
<%= form_for([@user, @school]) do |f| %>
  <!-- fields go here -->
<% end %>

# app/views/schools/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for([@user, @school]) do |f| %>
  <!-- fields go here -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks roboles. There will be multiple school records in the database but I want it treated as a singular resource from a routing standpoint as a user will only be dealing with a single school, as specified in their user record. Any idea what the significance of the '.1' is?

Comment: Hi Jerome, glad I can help. The routing for the school and user will depend upon if you intend to relate the same school to many different users. Let me know which your hoping to do and I can suggest something.

The '.1' on the end is the id of the school record being used in the form_for request. Behind the scenes the form_for method will look up the path required for the resource its given. In the case of your school record it finds a singular resource path and therefore appends the url with the object id as a by product of being able to attach extra parameters to a path.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that one school will have many users and, for now, a user will only ever be able to see the one school they are associated with. using 'resource :school' seems to make sense in this situation I think, I guess the problem is persuading form_for that it's dealing with a singleton resource so it doesn't need to append the id. I really appreciate your time and advice on this.

Comment: Cool, I have a couplemore questions... 1) is the schools table pre populated with a set of school records? 2) could you add a copy of your form template, so I can see what your trying to send to the controller?

Comment: Yes, it's pre-populated at the moment from a CSV file. At some point there's a requirement for admin users to be able to see all schools but that's some way down the line. Form template added above.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the relationship between your models and what your trying to do, I have added a possible solution to my original post. Let me know how it goes, and if this is what your after :)

Comment: Much appreciated, if I could vote your answer up more I would.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue with a singular profile resource in my routes.rb file:

```
resource :profile
```

It took me a few hours to find a solution so I decided to share it to save someone else the trouble.
I had to remove the "**(.:format)**" part of the route (shown when running "rake routes"), by specifying a specific format:

```
constraints :format => "html" do  
  resource :profile  
end
```

I also had to add the :url option to form_for tags:

```
<% form_for(@profile, :url => profile_path) %>
```

and that worked.